# In Scala what is difference between val a = "Hello World" and val a = println("Hello World")

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop, println

```
scala> val a = println("Hello World")
Hello World
a: Unit = ()
```

Why does the `a: Unit()` come ? we have assigned some value into `val a`.

But if we do like

`val a = "Hello World"` it only shows

`a: String = Hello World`

Here we assign some string into val a. so It is gives that.

In the 1st one, inbuilt function println() is called and it has some value, which it returns. is it??

Then why `a: Unit()` appears?

`a:Unit()` means- it can return anything !!!

Answer (score 2):

In scala there are no procedures, only functions.

The procedure is function with return type Unit.

Please see slide #45 from Martin Odersky http://www.slideshare.net/Typesafe/scaladays-keynote / http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=kkTFx3-duc8#t=2674 .

Though when you write

```
val a = println("Hi")
```

it is expands internally into

```
val a = { println("Hi") }
```

it is like an anonymous version of

```
def x() { println("Hi") }
val a = x()
```

The full version of the x() with all "sugar" removed is

```
def x():Unit = { println("Hi") }
```

And the Unit value is compacted into () in scala console.

So when you write your "compact version" you have :

```
val a = println("Hi")
Hi <-- result of the call to the println in the stdout
a:Unit = () <-- here a - name of variable, 
                Unit = type of the a variable, 
                and the () is the current value of a
```

Answer (score 1):

If your used to C or Java, the Unit type it's like void, the difference between the two examples you just gave is that `println` returns nothing, in Scala the return type is given by the last operation executed. If you follow up the `println` function you get to the java definition:

```
public void println(Object paramObject)
```

Which, as said before, has type `void`.

Other examples of unit return types are:

```
for {
  someValue <- someList
} // here the return type is unit because you are missing the yield

val a = ()
```

The second example instead is a value assignation, in Scala when you type `val a = "some string"` the compiler automatically infers the type of that variable (in this case String).

```
val someInt = 12 // Int
val someLong = 10L // Long
val someList = List("123", "456") // List[String]
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala contains a special type called Unit (a type synonym for it is also () ), similar to Java's void, which symbolizes no return value. The println function prints its argument to the default output device (stdout) and returns nothing.

Now, if you assign values in your input, the repl will print the values of each defined variable, eg.:

```
scala> val x = 5; val y = 1;
x: Int = 5
y: Int = 1
```

In your case, you assigned a the return value of println, which is the aforementioned Unit. In other words, the "Hello World" is a conseqence of the println and the a : Unit = () is a consequence of performing assignment in the repl.